# Integrating CKEditor with SmartGWT

Tags: ckeditor, smartgwt

I tried to integrate CKEditor in a SmartGWT application using the gwt-ckeditor module. But I get an error when I try to display the application, in dev-mode:

```
[ERROR] [Eureka] - 18:21:15.139:TMR5[E]:WARN:drawing:campaignMessageDesignPage_id:draw() called on widget with current drawn state: handleDrawn, ignoring.
    Class.getStackTrace(_1=>undef, _2=>undef, _3=>undef, _4=>undef)
    Canvas.readyToDraw()
    Canvas.draw(_1=>undef)
    Layout.layoutChildren(_1=>"resized", _2=>0, _3=>19)
    Canvas.$t1()
    Canvas.resizeBy(_1=>0, _2=>19, _3=>undef, _4=>undef)
    Canvas.resizeTo(_1=>1365, _2=>586, _3=>undef, _4=>undef)
    Layout.resizeMembers(_1=>Array[12], _2=>Array[12], _3=>true)
    ** recursed on Layout.layoutChildren


com.smartgwt.client.core.JsObject$SGWT_WARN: 10:35:18.045:TMR7[E]:WARN:drawing:campaignMessageDesignPage_id:draw() called on widget with current drawn state: handleDrawn, ignoring. 
    Class.getStackTrace(_1=>undef, _2=>undef, _3=>undef, _4=>undef)     Canvas.readyToDraw()     Canvas.draw(_1=>undef)     Layout.layoutChildren(_1=>"resized", _2=>0, _3=>19)     Canvas.$t1()     Canvas.resizeBy(_1=>0, _2=>19, _3=>undef, _4=>undef)     Canvas.resizeTo(_1=>1365, _2=>586, _3=>undef, _4=>undef)     Layout.resizeMembers(_1=>Array[12], _2=>Array[12], _3=>true)     ** recursed on Layout.layoutChildren 
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:105)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Here a piece of my code:

```
public class CampaignMessageDesignPage extends Page {

    protected VLayout mainLayout;

    protected CKEditor ckEditor;

    @Override
    protected void prepareMainLayoutCanvasCandidate() {
        mainLayout = createOrGetVLayoutById(campaignMessageDesignPage_id);
        mainLayout.setWidth100();
        mainLayout.setHeight100();
        mainLayout.setDefaultLayoutAlign(Alignment.CENTER);

        Canvas cnvEditor = new Canvas("cnvEditor");
        CKConfig conf = new CKConfig(PRESET_TOOLBAR.FULL);
        ckEditor = new CKEditor(conf);
        conf.setBaseFloatZIndex(1000000);
        conf.setUseFormPanel(false);
        ckEditor.setHTML("");
        ckEditor.setSize("100%", "100%");
        cnvEditor.addChild(ckEditor);
        cnvEditor.setSize("50%", "50%");

        mainLayout.setMembers(cnvEditor);
    }

    @Override
    protected final Canvas getMainLayoutCanvasCandidate() {
        return this.mainLayout;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(final SimpleBO param) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

The draw() method is called elsewhere.

Do you have any idea?

Edit:
I tried some different stuff. I tried to add standard GWT widgets to my SmartGWT layout and it worked fine, so it's really a CKEditor related problem.

I also tried to create the content on page display, and obtained another error message, hopefully more useful:

```
18:45:06.698 [ERROR] [Eureka] 18:45:06.697:RDQ0[E]:WARN:Log:TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
    unnamed() @ 
    unnamed() @ unknown source
    unnamed() @ Eureka/hosted.html?Eureka:76:35
    unnamed() @ Eureka/hosted.html?Eureka:54:12
    onDraw() @ unknown source
    Canvas.draw() @ Eureka/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js:2123:6
    Canvas.drawChildren() @ Eureka/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js:2177:197
    Canvas.draw() @ Eureka/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js:2114:247
    Layout._drawNonMemberChildren() @ Eureka/sc/modules/ISC_Foundation.js:374:21
    Layout.drawChildren() @ Eureka/sc/modules/ISC_Foundation.js:365:130
    Canvas.draw() @ Eureka/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js:2114:247
com.smartgwt.client.core.JsObject$SGWT_WARN: 18:45:06.697:RDQ0[E]:WARN:Log:TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
    unnamed() @ 
    unnamed() @ unknown source
    unnamed() @ Eureka/hosted.html?Eureka:76:35
    unnamed() @ Eureka/hosted.html?Eureka:54:12
    onDraw() @ unknown source
    Canvas.draw() @ Eureka/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js:2123:6
    Canvas.drawChildren() @ Eureka/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js:2177:197
    Canvas.draw() @ Eureka/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js:2114:247
    Layout._drawNonMemberChildren() @ Eureka/sc/modules/ISC_Foundation.js:374:21
    Layout.drawChildren() @ Eureka/sc/modules/ISC_Foundation.js:365:130
    Canvas.draw() @ Eureka/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js:2114:247
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:105)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: For some reason, a piece of the error trace was missing. I just added it.

Comment: Actually, I switched to TinyMCE, which works much better with SmartGWT.

Comment: As I didn't got any answer, I understand it means the GWTCKEditor library is broken, at least for the last SmartGWT versions? That's a shame...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a component that does this for you in the SmartGWT-Extensions Google Code project:

http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt-extensions/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fmainprojects%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fsmartgwt%2Fextensions%2Fhtmleditor%2Fclient

Comment: Actually, this uses an old version of FCKEditor, which isn't maintained anymore...

Comment: You should still take a look at that code as it's a working example of embedding a third-party JS widget.  Note that the warning you're reporting is just a warning - it indicates an unnecessary call to draw(), but doesn't explain your problem.  Instead, you should compare your code to the SmartGWT-Extensions example, and/or use a tool like Firebug to see the DOM and try to figure out why CKEditor isn't drawing.

Comment: I will look into it. For the record, my current (non-working code) comes from http://code.google.com/p/gwt-ckeditor/issues/detail?id=27 Maybe it's a version issue? Do you think this code should still work with the current version of SmarGWT?

Comment: I took a look on SmartGWT-Extensions, and obviously, it isn't maintained anymore and is actually unable to work with the current version of SmartGWT.